# Displaying percentage in customized ticks

Tags: plotting, style, ticks, frame

Consider the following plot, where the ticks were customized

```
tickFunc = 
  MapAt[Reverse, {All, 3}]@*
   Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, 
    "TicksLength" -> {.01, .005}];

ListLinePlot[RandomReal[1, 30], Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{tickFunc[##] &, None}, {tickFunc[##] &, None}}]
```

[image]

Now, I want to keep the same tick style but display the axes as a percentage using `PercentForm`.

Here's my attempt

```
tickFunc2 = 
  Module[{rawTicks}, 
    rawTicks = 
     Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, 
       "TicksLength" -> {.01, .005}][##];
    rawTicks = MapAt[Reverse, rawTicks, {All, 3}]; 
    MapAt[PercentForm[#] &, rawTicks, {All, 2}]] &;

ListLinePlot[RandomReal[1, 30], Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{tickFunc2[##] &, None}, {tickFunc2[##] &, None}}]
```

[image]

As you can see, the y-axis is not affected by this. Any ideas on how to fix my code?

Answer (score 6):

Replace `PercentForm[#] &` with `PercentForm[# /. NumberForm[a_, ___] :> PercentForm[Round[a, .01]]] &`:

```
tickFunc2 =  Module[{rawTicks}, 
  rawTicks = Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, 
      "TicksLength" -> {.01, .005}][##];
  rawTicks = MapAt[Reverse, rawTicks, {All, 3}];
  MapAt[PercentForm[# /. NumberForm[a_, ___] :> PercentForm[Round[a, .01]]] &, 
      rawTicks, {All, 2}]] &;

ListLinePlot[RandomReal[1, 30], Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{tickFunc2[##] &, None}, {tickFunc2[##] &, None}}]
```

[image]

**Note:** The reason for the unexpected result is that non-integer labels are wrapped with `NumberForm`:

```
InputForm @ tickFunc2[0, 1]
```

[image]

Compare this with:

```
InputForm @ tickFunc2[0, 100]
```

[image]